# How to render the weapon animation separately, without a character, to create a video game sprites?

Tags: rendering, animation

I need to create some weapon sprites in Blender, that will be used in a video game. First I need to export the png sequences of character animation without weapons and then export the same action with a weapon only, on transparent background. But the most important thing is, to have the impact of the character in the weapon animation. I.e if it’s about sword, it has to be rendered with a placeholder of the character hand, which means that the grip of the sword will have a hole (which is meant to be a character hand ), so that if the sword animation sequence is placed above the character animation, it looked as if the character is holding the sword.

When I try to export only the weapon sequence, it is rendered as the character was transparent, rendereing the sword fully in all positions… Please help

Comment: Some of the cooler sword wielding moves will have the sword pass behind the character. How do you plan to handle that? There are some things which cannot be done in 2D png stack...

Comment: Not sure what u mean... Can you clarify your question?

Comment: You talk about a placeholder for the hand, which makes the sword transparent/invisible where the hand should be, so that the hand of the underlying character png stays visible. You do not talk about a placeholder for e.g. the characters head. So if the character takes a wide swing with the sword, then the sword will stay visible in spite of the fact that it should become hidden by the head, if it is passing behind the characters head. If your moves are only so that nothing but the character hand will ever hide the sword, then they are less complex, which I decribed as "boring".

Comment: Oh... I see... But I didn't mean only the hand mask, but everything intersecting it. I've found the way here, on Blenderstackexchange, but can't fully implement it... It's about changing pass index to 1.0 instead of 0.0 to the object that should be masked. The rest remains the same 0.0 index, this way some changes should be applied only to the "sword" for example and everything that will have a contact with it will become transparent... I follow the process but can't get rid of the white background for some reason...